# android listview load more on scroll But method not called after 1st scroll listview

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I want to implement endless scroll for list view I have used [This Link](http://www.avocarrot.com/blog/implement-infinitely-scrolling-list-android/) and my code is

```
lvproduct.setOnScrollListener(new InfiniteScrollListener(10) {
            @Override
            public void loadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {
                System.out.println("LOAD MORE **" +totalItemsCount+" "+totalItemsCount+10+"");
                getProducts(totalItemsCount,totalItemsCount+10);
               // setUp(totalItemsCount,5);
                gridViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

my problem is

- problem  1:when it load data no data display on screen but when I
  just scroll it display data (actually it have data checked in adpter and prints data in log)
- problem 2:after 1 scroll this not call    getProducts method

Please help me 
I have make same interface as **InfiniteScrollListener** in link

Answer (score 0):

1) problem 1:~ You can put to lines into your XML for the Problem

```
android:divider="@null"
android:dividerHeight="0dp"
```